# Can I use union all statement with insert into statement in teradata?

Tags: sql, teradata, teradata-sql-assistant, teradatasql

I have two tables with same number of columns and same data types. I want to union then with "union all" statement and want to insert the resultant values into another table.

I am using this query

```
    INSERT into DB.HRfinal

select LoginID,JobTitle,Name from DB.HR1
UNION ALL
select LoginID,JobTitle,Name from DB.HR2
```

but it's only inserting values from first table
as there are 256 rows in HR1 table and 230 rows in HR2 table but its only inserting 256 rows in HRfinal Table

Comment: This should work.  Perhaps you are not executing the entire query or the second table is empty.

Comment: I am executing entire query by selecting entire query and pressing F5. and second table is not empty.

Comment: I tried using this one query too but I got error of "too many expressions in the select list of a subquery" when I run this query
  INSERT into DB.HRfinal
select(
select LoginID,JobTitle,Name from DB.HR1
UNION ALL
select LoginID,JobTitle,Name from DB.HR2)

Comment: @irfangonal . . . Try running the query in your question.  The version in your comment is not correct.

Comment: I have tried running that one again but same results. I think maybe structure of this query is little different in teradata, what do you say?

Comment: got it. I was using union mistakenly instead of union all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recreated your example and got rows from both tables in final table.

I suspect that the problem is on union level not in insert part.

Try:

step 1.

```
SELECT * INTO #tmp
(select LoginID,JobTitle,Name from DB.HR1
UNION ALL
select LoginID,JobTitle,Name from DB.HR2) TMP
```

check if the #tmp table has all rows. If it has then:

Step 2.

```
INSERT into DB.HRfinal
SELECT * FROM #tmp
```

Comment: it says "Select failed.3706: Syntax error: INTO clause is not allowed
P.s I am using teradata sql assistant

Comment: Try then: INSERT into DB.HRfinal select * from 
(select LoginID,JobTitle,Name from DB.HR1
UNION ALL
select LoginID,JobTitle,Name from DB.HR2) TMP

Comment: Btw, no need for ( )